# Example of a general random variable with finite mean but infinite variance

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, lebesgue-measure, expectation

Given a probability triple $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ of Lebesgue measure $[0,1]$, find a random variable $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ such that the expected value $E(X)$ converges to a finite, positive value, but $E(X^2)$ diverges.

Comment: Hint: think of Pareto random variables.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One answer is Pareto distribution with parameters $\alpha , x_0$ which are both positive. The distribution is given by:

$$f_X(x)= \begin{cases} \alpha\,\frac{x_0^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}} & x \ge x_0, \\ 0 & x < x_0. \end{cases}$$

Note that $E[X] = \infty$ for $\alpha \leq 1$ and is finite elsewhere.

The variance is not finite for $\alpha \in [1,2) $

Hence it satisfies your question for $(1,2)$

In general,$E[X^n]= \infty \ \ ;n\geq \alpha$.

**EDIT**: Clarified the answer as suggested.

Comment: Are there any limitations on $\alpha$ or will this work for _any_ positive value of $\alpha$, say $\alpha = 5$?

Comment: Distribution is defined for $\alpha > 0$ but the question is satisfied for $\alpha \in (1,2]$ as then expectation is finite and variance infinite.., for $\alpha \leq 1$ expectation is infinite, variance doesn't exist..  but

Comment: So maybe you could include the restriction on $\alpha$ in your answer so that anyone who just looks at the answer has the complete correct answer to the question of a random variable with finite mean and divergent $E[X^2]$.  For $\alpha > 2$, both $E[X]$ _and_ $E[X^2]$ are finite.

Comment: TheJoker and @DilipSarwate is my answer correct please?

Answer (score 7):

An example is a random variable $X$ having a [student-t distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) with $\nu = 2$ degrees of freedom

Its mean is $E[X] = 0$ for $\nu > 1$, but its second moment $E[X^2] = Var[X] = \infty$ for $1 < \nu \le 2$

---

**Edit**: Oh wait, finite positive. Well, $X+1$, I guess.

Answer (score 5):

One can consider a discrete random variables with support $\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X=m)=C\frac{1}{m^3}$ for some $C>0$. Then $\mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}C\frac{1}{m^2}<\infty$ but $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}C\frac{1}{m}$ diverges since it is the harmonic series.