# example of random variable that is integrable but have infinite second moment

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Can anybody give an example of nonnegative random variable assuming integer

values, almost surely, which is integrable but that has infinite second moment?

Comment: Try $P(X=n)=p_n$ where $p_n=c_q n^{-q}$ for some appropriate $q>0$ and a normalization constant $c_q$.

Comment: Taking $q=2$ it works right?

Comment: No, then the first moment is infinite. You are close though.

Comment: right, so if $q=3$, then the first moment is finite but the second infinite

Comment: The "St. Petersburg paradox" is such an example.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\Pr(X>x) = \dfrac 1 {x^\alpha}$ for $x\ge 1$.

Then $f_X(x) = \alpha x^{-\alpha-1}$ for $x\ge 1$.

So $\operatorname{E}(X) = \dfrac \alpha {1-\alpha}$ if $\alpha>1$.

And $\operatorname{E}(X^2) = \dfrac \alpha {2-\alpha}$ if $\alpha>2$.

If $1<\alpha<2$ then $\operatorname{E}(X)<\infty$ and $\operatorname{E}(X^2) = \infty.$

---

Now let's try a similar one with integer values in the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$.

$$ \text{Let } \zeta(\alpha) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-\alpha}. $$

$$ \Pr(X=n) =  \dfrac{n^{-\alpha}}{\zeta(\alpha)}.$$

(This is sometimes called a Zipf distribution, after George Kingsley Zipf.)

As above, $\operatorname{E}(X)<\infty$ if $\alpha>2$ and $\operatorname{E}(X^2) = \infty$ if $\alpha>3$.

Comment: but it have to assume interger values almost everywhere

Comment: See other examples (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/236181) for the non-discrete case.

Comment: A minor typo: I think you mean $\operatorname{E}(X)<\infty$ if $\alpha>2$ and $\operatorname{E}(X^2) = \infty$ if $\alpha<3$.