# Integrable random variable X such that X^2 is not integrable

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables, riemann-integration

can anyone  help me?
I have to show an example of an integrable random variable X such that X^2 is not integrable (it is not specified discrete or continuos case)
I know that a r.v. is integrable if and only if its expected value is well-defined  and is said to be square integrable if the expected value of its square exists and it is well-defined. But I have not idea what type of random variable respects as I requested.
Thank you in advance

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1955968/example-of-random-variable-that-is-integrable-but-have-infinite-second-moment

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ have support $[1,\infty)$ and pdf $f_X(x)=\frac{2}{x^3}.$ $X$ is integrable since $\int_1^\infty x\frac{2}{x^3}dx = 2,$ but $X^2$ is not since $\int_1^\infty x^2\frac{2}{x^3}dx$ diverges.

Comment: I must ask, why the factor of $2$?

Comment: @ShaiDeshe So we have $\int_1^\infty \frac{2}{x^3}dx=1$