# Chebyshev's inequality assumptions

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

Why does Chebyshev's inequality demand that $\mathbb{E(}X^2) < \infty$?

Comment: Can the variance exist if the second moment doesn't?

Comment: The variance wont exist, but surely if $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$ = $\infty$ then $Var(X)$ = $\infty$.  RHS of Chebyshev's inequality is $\infty$ and probability measures codomain is less than 1 (LHS <= 1)so the inequality still holds?

Comment: It appears to me that one could weaken the assumption of finite variance to the assumption that $\operatorname E(|X|)<+\infty,$ and Chebyshev's inequality would survive.

Comment: @MichaelHardy By your own answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1955968/example-of-random-variable-that-is-integrable-but-have-infinite-second-moment .We have there exists $\mathbb{E}(X)$ finite and $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$ infinite. So $\mathbb{E}(|X|)$ finite would not be enough to address that concern.

Comment: If $\sigma=\infty$ the inequality is true, but not interesting.

Comment: @saulspatz An assumption, in itself, infers that if that assumption is false then the "statement" is no longer true. I understand that it may work with infinity, but why would it be an assumption, that is to say, why not leave $\mathbb{E}(X^2) < \infty$ out of Chebyshev's inequality alltogether? My opinion is that, since it is an assumption, Chebysnev's inequality must be false if $\mathbb{E}(X^2) = \infty$ so I believe that the inequality is false if var = inf but dont know why that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write  Chebyshev's inequality as $$\mathbb P(|X-\mu|\geq k\sigma) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$$ or equivalently as $$\mathbb P(|X-\mu|\geq t) \leq \frac{\sigma ^2}{t^2}$$

with $k, t > 0$.

If $\mathbb E[X^2]=\infty$ then $\sigma^2=\mathbb E[X^2]-\mu^2=\infty$ and so you find $\mathbb P(|X-\mu|\geq t) \leq \infty$.

This would not be useful information, as you already know that $\mathbb P(|X-\mu|\geq t) \leq 1$ since it is a probability.

Comment: So it holds for $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$ = $\infty$? I am not sure that your answer addresses the question. Please elaborate.

Comment: @KianVaru In either formulation it is totally useless (though not untrue) when $\mathbb E[X]$ is finite and $\mathbb E[X^2]=\infty$ as $\sigma =\infty$ too

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise $\mathbb{E(}X) $ may not exist.

Comment: But the weaker statement that $\operatorname E(|X|) <+\infty$ would be enough to address that concern.

Comment: @MichaelHardy You are right, but the case $\mathbb{E(}X^2) = +\infty$ is not interesting (it gives an infinite superior bound). So I guess we ask $\mathbb{E(}X^2) < +\infty$ to be sure that $\mathbb{E(}X)$ exists *and* to get an interesting inequality. I don't see any other reason, do you see one ? (I am not so good in probability so maybe there is something obvious I miss ^^)

Comment: @MichaelHardy See the first answer bottom line of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1955968/example-of-random-variable-that-is-integrable-but-have-infinite-second-moment .We have there exists $\mathbb{E}(X)$ finite and $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$ infinite. So $\mathbb{E}(|X|)$ finite would not be enough to address that concern.

Comment: @KianVaru : Why not? The example you cite is merely an instance in whcih $\operatorname E(|X|)<+\infty$ and $\operatorname E(X^2)=+\infty.$ Certainly there are such instances, but why would that mean that the statement that $\operatorname E(X)<+\infty$ is not enought to address the concern?

Comment: @MichaelHardy So if E$(|X|) <\infty$ then there are instances E$(X^2) = +\infty$ like you mentioned. So Var(X) wont exist as we have trouble defining the Variance. My point is the stronger condition E$(X^2) < \infty$ must hold so that Var$(X) = \mathbb{E}((X-\mathbb{E}(X^2))^2)$ is well defined.

Comment: @KianVaru : One could say it's well defined to be $+\infty$ and in that case the inequality is true.

Comment: $$ \operatorname{var}(X) = \operatorname E\Big(\big(X-\operatorname E(X)\big)^2\Big) $$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes I agree, thank you for clarifying.