# Expectation of the square of a random variable

Tags: inequality, random-variables, expected-value

Jensen's inequality implies that
$$ (\mathbb{E}[X])^2 \le \mathbb{E}[X^2] $$

Is there any bound for the following formula

$$ 1\le\frac{\mathbb{E}[X^2]}{(\mathbb{E}[X])^2} \le \text{?} $$
where $X>0$ is a random variable.

Comment: See the solution in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1955968/example-of-random-variable-that-is-integrable-but-have-infinite-second-moment.

Comment: No such bound is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the normal distribution with expected value $\mu$ and variance $1.$

As $\mu\to0,$ the proposed ratio approaches $+\infty.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mu_j:=\mathsf{E} X^j$. Using Markov's inequality,
$$
\theta\,\mathsf{P}\!\left(X>\theta\mu_2^{1/2}\right)\le \frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2^{1/2}}, \quad \theta>0,
$$
one gets
$$
1\le \frac{\mu_2}{\mu_1^2}\le \inf_{\theta>0}\left[\theta\,\mathsf{P}\!\left(X>\theta\mu_2^{1/2}\right)\right]^{-2}.
$$