# Is $\mathbf{E}[X|\mathcal{F}]$ not $\mathbf{P}_{\mathcal{F}}$ - a.s. finite ？

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A}, \mathbf{P})$ be a probability space, $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{A}$  be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra.Let $X$ an $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variable and $\mathbf{E}[X|\mathcal{F}]$ is a conditional expectation of $X$ given $\mathcal{F}$. According to the definition of $\mathbf{E}[X|\mathcal{F}]$,we know it is $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$-measurable and defined on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \mathbf{P}_{\mathcal{F}}),$ where $\mathbf{P}_{\mathcal{F}}$ means $\mathbf{P}$ restricted to $\mathcal{F}$.

I want find some examples such that $\mathbf{E}[X|\mathcal{F}]$ is not $\mathbf{P}_{\mathcal{F}}$-a.s. finite. (i.e. there is a subset $S(\in\mathcal{F})$ of $\Omega$, such that $\mathbf{P}_{\mathcal{F}}(S)>0$ and $S=\left\{\omega\in\Omega:|\mathbf{E}[X|\mathcal{F}](\omega)|=\infty\right\}).$

---

**Addition**

Based on previous discussions among everyone, I give my opinions.

***1.***

*Conditional expectations* can be extensively defined for random variables with infinite expectation，if we allow those random variables' conditional expectations are $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$-measurable by *Radon-Nikodym*'s theorem,where $\overline{\mathbb{R}}=[-\infty,\infty].$ In this cases, we only need the integral of $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variable X exists.It is not necessary that $X$ to be integrable.

***2.***

Let $\mathcal{F}= \left\{\varnothing,  \Omega\right\}$,there must exists an $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variable $X$, such that $\mathbf{E}[X]=\infty$ [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1955968/example-of-random-variable-that-is-integrable-but-have-infinite-second-moment). $\mathbf{E}[X|\mathcal{F}]$ is a conditional expectation of $X$ given $\mathcal{F},$ so $$\int_{B}\mathbf{E}[X|\mathcal{F}]d\mathbf{P_{\mathcal{F}}}=\int_{B}X d\mathbf{P},\quad \forall B\in \mathcal{F}= \left\{\varnothing,  \Omega\right\}.$$ Let $B=\Omega,$ then we have $$\int_{\Omega}\mathbf{E}[X|\mathcal{F}]d\mathbf{P_{\mathcal{F}}}=\int_{\Omega}X d\mathbf{P}=\infty.$$
Since $\mathbf{E}[X|\mathcal{F}]$ is $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$-measurable, $\mathbf{E}[X|\mathcal{F}]$ needs to be a constant on $\Omega$.

$\mathbf{P_{\mathcal{F}}}$ is a finite measure,hence we need $\mathbf{E}[X|\mathcal{F}]=\infty$ on $\Omega$.

Comment: You cannot. The conditional expectation only exists for random variables $X$ that have finite expectation $E(|X|) < \infty.$

Comment: @WilliamM. Maybe we can generalise to the case where $X \ge 0$, in which case there still exists a $\mathcal{F}$-measurable r.v. which behaves a lot like the conditional expectation.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, conditional expectations only exist for random variables with finite expectation (i.e., $E(|X|) < \infty).$ Let us assume that $X \geq 0,$ so that $E(X)$ is well-define (possibly $+\infty$) and let us try to define $E(X \mid \mathscr{F}).$ The usual way would be to apply Radon-Nikodym derivative to the measure $F \mapsto \int_F X dP$ for $F \in \mathscr{F}$ which is still absolutely continuous relative to $P.$ However, we require now that $F \mapsto \int_F X dP$ be $\sigma$-finite, otherwise the derivative may not exist. As a consequence, there is an partition $(F_n)$ of $\Omega$ such that $\int_{F_n} X dP < \infty.$ This will force the Radon-Nikodym derivative to be finite $P$-a.e. on $F_n$ as well, i.e. $E(X \mid \mathscr{F}) \mid_{F_n} < \infty$ $P$-a.e., and therefore, $E(X \mid \mathscr{F}) < \infty$ $P$-a.e. (Note that this argument also shows that $E(X \mid \mathscr{F}) \geq 0$ $P$-a.e.)

**By the way,** if $E(|X|) < \infty,$ then $|X| < \infty$ $P$-a.e. and since $|E(X \mid \mathscr{F})| \leq E(|X| \mid \mathscr{F})$ and the latter has expectation $E(|X|) < \infty,$ we see that $E(X \mid \mathscr{F})$ is finite $P$-a.e.

**A comment.** $E(X \mid \mathscr{F})$ intuitively has for values the "average" of $X$ on the subsets of $F.$ As a consequence, if $X$ takes an infinite value with positive probability, then any reasonable extension of $E(X \mid \mathscr{F})$ will be infinite on the same set (and since $\mathscr{F}$ is coarser than the original sigma field, that means that $E(X \mid \mathscr{F})$ has a chance of being infinite on a larger set than $X$ is). However, the argument given above shows that provided $X$ has finite absolute expectation on a subset of $\mathscr{F},$ then so $E(|X| \mid \mathscr{F})$ will be finite on that subset, and this forces finiteness $P$-a.e. on that subset of the condition expectation.

Comment: Afaik the definition of conditional expectation is just that
$\mathbb E[X|{\cal F}]$ is a r.v. that it is ${\cal F}$-measurable and satisfies
$$
\int_B X\,d\mathbb P=\int_B \mathbb E[X|{\cal F}]\,d\mathbb P \quad\forall B\in {\cal F}\,.
$$ 
The pathological example
$$
X:=\infty 1_A\,,\;{\cal F}=\sigma(1_B)\,,\;\;\mathbb E[X|{\cal F}]=\infty1_B
$$
should fit into this definition.

Comment: Viewing conditional expectation as $L^2$ projection, and extended to non-negative random variables (elements) by approximation and limits, and considering $E(\infty \mid \mathcal F)$ would mean that $E(\infty \mid \mathcal F) = \infty$.

Comment: @KurtG. the usual definition includes $X$ to be integrable. Sometimes a little hidden. For example, the book of Klenke Probability Theory do not state $X \in \mathscr{L}^1$ in the definition but rather during the discussion towards the definition.

Comment: @Andrew if one does not assume $X$ to be finite a.s. and extend the definition of conditional expectation to include this case, well $E(X \mid \mathscr{F})$ should be infinite at least on the same set where $X$ is infinite. (Note that the question assumes $X < \infty$ a.e.)

Comment: I think we agree and that there are only pathological examples that fit into the formal minimal definition.

Comment: @user250236 in your example $E(X \mid \mathscr{F}) = \infty$ everywhere, thus it is infinity _at least_ on the same set where $X$ is infinity.

Comment: Actually, I meant that although $X$ is $\mathbf{P}$-a.s. finite, $E(X \mid \mathscr{F})$ may not be  $\mathbf{P_{\mathscr{F}}}$-a.s. finite, as described in my example.So we find the example that satisfied my original post’s requirement.

Comment: @user250236 $\mathbf{P}\mid_\mathscr{F}$ is just the restriction of $\mathbf{P}$, right?

Comment: Yes it is.Where $\mathbf{P}_{\mathscr{F}}$ means $\mathbf{P}$ restricted to $\mathscr{F}.$