# Random variable $X$ with $E[X]\in\mathbb{R}, E[X^{2}] \not\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, expected-value

Does anyone know a example of a random variable  $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$  which $$E[X] \in \mathbb{R}$$  but $$E[X^{2}] \not\in \mathbb{R}\:?$$

Comment: Take $P(X=n)=\frac{1}{\zeta(3)n^3}$ for each $n \geq 1$.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236181/example-of-a-general-random-variable-with-finite-mean-but-infinite-variance?

Comment: $c/(1+|x|^3)$ where $c$ is a normalizing factor.

Comment: $X(\omega) = {1 \over \sqrt{\omega}}$ on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Sorry, that should be $(0,1)$ with uniform distribution.